# Create document if it doesn't exist in MongoDB and add fields to it atomically

Tags: python, mongodb, acid

I have a collection called users. I want to add a user to that collection but it should fail if a user with the same name already exists. If creation succeeds I would like to initialize it with some data, e.g. password hash.

I cannot use an update upsert like follows:

```
name = ...
password_hash = ...
db.users.update({ "name": name }, { "name": name, "hash": password_hash }, upsert=True)
```

because that would overwrite the password hash of an existing user. Essentially I want to atomically do the following:

```
name = ...
password_hash = ...
if db.users.find_one({ "name": name }) is None: # Line A
    db.users.insert_one({ "name": name, "hash": password_hash }) # Line B
```

However I cannot use that exact code because a user with `name` could be added between Line A and Line B meaning I would have two users with the same name.

I also cannot use an empty `upsert` and then add the data afterwards in the case that it created a new user, because that data may be queried between the user being created and the data being added. I.e. it is not atomic.

I have tried reading other SO questions and answers (they all suggest the empty `upsert` method which doesn't work), have tried reading the documentation and have tried general googling without being able to find anything. I am using Python so if you can write an answer in Python that would be good but don't avoid answering if you have to write it in a different language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an index and specify that name is a unique field.
take a look here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/

that should solve you problem.

Any update / insert operation that don't comply with the index will fail.